# How to design a Windows Forms App with Iron Python

Tags: python, ironpython, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I just got Visual Studio 2013 RC with PTVS ([Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)). How would I use the Windows Forms Designer that Visual Studio has built in with Python? VS has an Iron Python template for WF, but there's no way to use the actual GUI designer. Is there any way to get the GUI designer functionality with python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python Tools for Visual Studio does not have a Windows Forms designer. You could take a look at [SharpDevelop which does have a Windows Forms designer for IronPython](https://web.archive.org/web/20190831050111/http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2009/05/12/IronPython2FormsDesigner.aspx). The other alternative would be to design your form in C# and then in your IronPython project use that form as the base class for your IronPython class.